# Gluonhq VideoService

Tags: javafxports

I m developing a media player app and I m using VideoService for this purpose, my issue is the app life cycle when its minmized in backgroud while playing first its pause the video and i handle this in pause handler,  when i maximize the app i call videoservice.play() but it play for a second and the whole app stuck in black screen and crash at the end.
if i dont call videoservice.play it will just crash, here my sample code.

```
private void initVideoService(VideoService service) {
    videoService = service;
    videoService.setPosition(Pos.CENTER, 0, 40, 0, 40);
    videoService.setControlsVisible(true);
    videoService.fullScreenProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> MobileApplication.getInstance().getAppBar().setVisible(!nv));    MobileApplication.getInstance().getAppBar().getActionItems().addAll(playButton, stopButton, fullScreenButton);
    videoService.statusProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
        System.out.println(String.format("FullScreenCondition : %b", nv != MediaPlayer.Status.PLAYING && nv != MediaPlayer.Status.PAUSED));
        fullScreenButton.setDisable(nv != MediaPlayer.Status.PLAYING && nv != MediaPlayer.Status.PAUSED);
        if (videoService.statusProperty().get() == MediaPlayer.Status.PLAYING) {
            System.out.println("Video is Playing");
            playButton.setGraphic(MaterialDesignIcon.PAUSE.graphic());
            videoService.setFullScreen(true);
        } else if (videoService.statusProperty().get() == MediaPlayer.Status.PAUSED) {
            System.out.println("Video is paused");
            playButton.setGraphic(MaterialDesignIcon.PLAY_ARROW.graphic());
            videoService.setFullScreen(false);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Video is Stopped");
            playButton.setGraphic(MaterialDesignIcon.PLAY_ARROW.graphic());
            videoService.setFullScreen(false);
        }
    });
    Services.get(LifecycleService.class).ifPresent(s -> {
        s.addListener(LifecycleEvent.PAUSE, () -> {
            System.out.println("paused");
            videoService.pause();
        });
        s.addListener(LifecycleEvent.RESUME, () -> {
            System.out.println("Resumed");
            videoService.play();
        });
    });
} 
public void navToEpisode(Episode epi) {
    Services.get(VideoService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
        initVideoService(service);
    });
    RestClient.execute(new RestOperation() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String videoDownloadLink = RestUtils.getVideoDownloadLink(epi.getLinkToEpisode());
            try {
                publish(() ->
                {
                    if (Platform.isAndroid() || Platform.isIOS()) {
                        videoService.getPlaylist().add(videoDownloadLink);
                        videoService.play();
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you are on Android, run from command line  `adb logcat -v threadtime ` and run your app again. Find the stacktrace on the console and post it here. You can find `adb`  in the Android SDK folder, under platform-tools.

Comment: You can edit your question and post the relevant part of the stacktrace or add a link to the file (I. e. from pastebin)